# How can i stop the voicemail recording by pressing # key using twiml

Tags: twilio

I cannot find relevant TwiML code to achieve the following:

I am able to do the voice recording and send it to the email through this code, but one thing I am unable to do is add the code to detect the # key and to disconnect the recording while recording voicemail.

### Here is the code

I am using twimlets

```
 
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
        <Response>  
    <Say>  
    You have reached the Voicemail. At the tone please leave a detailed message.  
    </Say>  
    <Record transcribe="true" transcribeCallback="[1]:http://twimlets.com  
    /voicemail?Email=sshaheryarali@gmail.com"/>  
    </Response>
```

Please help me out in this matter

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Use the `finishOnKey="#"` attribute to the `<Record>` verb to accomplish this.

For example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say>  
    You have reached the Voicemail. At the tone please leave a detailed message.  
    </Say>
    <Record transcribe="true" finishOnKey="#" transcribeCallback="https://1e34f295exxx.ngrok.io/api/transcript"/>
</Response>
```

More detail is located here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#attributes-finishonkey

You will get a response to your callback URL similar to this (IDs redacted)

```
200 POST /api/transcript │ Response Type application/json; charset=utf-8
/api/transcript event: 

{
  request: {
    headers: {
      host: '1e34f295exxx.ngrok.io',
      'user-agent': 'TwilioProxy/1.1',
      'content-length': '890',
      accept: '*/*',
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
      'x-home-region': 'us1',
      'x-twilio-signature': 'JDoXrQtzWzg9HXkWEnezv3XKBKo=',
      'accept-encoding': 'gzip'
    },
    cookies: {}
  },
  ApiVersion: '2010-04-01',
  TranscriptionType: 'fast',
  TranscriptionUrl: 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Recordings/RExxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Transcriptions/TRxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  TranscriptionSid: 'TRxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  Called: '+6134240xxxx',
  RecordingSid: 'RExxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  CallStatus: 'completed',
  RecordingUrl: 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Recordings/RExxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  From: '+61467601932',
  Direction: 'inbound',
  url: 'https://1e34f295exxx.ngrok.io/api/transcript',
  AccountSid: 'ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  TranscriptionText: 'This is a detailed message.',
  Caller: '+61467601xxx',
  TranscriptionStatus: 'completed',
  CallSid: 'CAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  To: '+6134240xxxx',
  ForwardedFrom: '+6134240xxxx'
}
```

Comment: I am not a twiml expert. Please tell me how to Use the finishOnKey="#" attribute to the <Record>

Comment: Checkout the example in my response, it has your code updated with the attribute (on line 6)

Comment: I have checked the code when I press the # key it would repeat the <say> block and start the whole message again so I have multiple email of same message in my email address

Comment: I am using twiml bin it shows the same error that I describe earlier please help me out in this matter.

Comment: christopher can you please confirm that you have used the above code you provided on twiml bin because it gave me the same result as I told you before?

Comment: Yes confirmed with the version above, including the response. Note that in your request the URL is invalid as it contains "[1]:" prior to the callback URL

Comment: I have used this code

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
        <Response>  
    <Say>  
    You have reached the Voicemail. At the tone please leave a detailed message.  
    </Say>  
    <Record transcribe="true" finishOnKey="#" transcribeCallback="http://twimlets.com  
    /voicemail?Email=sshaheryarali@gmail.com"/>  
    </Response>

When I press the # key it repeats the message and restarts the voicemail process this way two emails are generated on the single voicemail.